# How to call ASP.Net pages from a DLL?

Tags: asp.net, system.reflection, in-house-distribution

I am developing a Web Application in Visual Studio 2008 (ASP.Net C#). My application currently has the following pages: 
1. MasterPage.Master 
2. Default.aspx  
3. Login.aspx 
4. Logout.aspx 
5. ReportPrint.aspx

Now, I have to in-house-distribute this application to my Developers for further development. For that, I dont want to give pages such as Login.aspx, Logout.aspx, ReportPrint.aspx since they are already complete.

Hence, I compiled these forms in a separate Web Application to create a DLL. Now I am trying to refer to this DLL and call pages which are compiled in it, but without any success.

In windows forms, we can easily refer to Forms from a DLL using :

```
DllName.FormName.show()
```

How to accomplish this using ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

The markup won't be part of the DLL; so as it currently stands you'll need to give the markup pages (.aspx files) to your team along with the compiled DLL (which will contain the code behind, ie aspx.cs).

See [Sharing ASCX-controls between different web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678911/sharing-ascx-controls-between-different-web-applications) for other solutions.

Comment: Agreed. Is it not possible to not give the Markup at all? Maybe we could create Virtual Directories in IIS and my developers could refer to them. Is that possible?